# Onclick not working in IE or Firefox but does work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome, onclick

I am trying to get Onclick to work in IE or Firefox but whatever I do it does not work, apart from in Chrome.

```
<h2 onclick="javascript:window.location.href='<?php echo $cbox['read_more_url'];?>';" style="cursor: pointer;"><?php echo $cbox['title'];?></h2> 
        <img src="<?php echo $cbox['image']['sizes']['gallery_large'] ?>" height="<?php echo $cbox['image']['sizes']['gallery_large-height'] ?>" width="<?php echo $cbox['image']['sizes']['gallery_large-width'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $cbox['title']; ?>" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='<?php echo $cbox['title_url'];?>';" style="cursor: pointer;"/>
```

I also tried just location.href and just window.location but still no go. Here is the site http://www.tradewindgroup.com.au/ The code refers to 3 headers Construction - Plumbing - and their images below, It works fine in Chrome.

THanks

Comment: just remove "javascript:". Why don't you wanna use <a href="..."></a>?

Comment: I could not get just a href to work.

Comment: Try this: <h2><a href="<?=$cbox['read_more_url']?>"><?=$cbox['title']?></a></h2> <a href="<?=$cbox['title_url']?>"><img src="<?=$cbox['image']['sizes']['gallery_large']?>" height="<?=$cbox['image']['sizes']['gallery_large-height']?>" width="<?=$cbox['image']['sizes']['gallery_large-width']?>" alt="<?=$cbox['title']?>"/>

Answer (score 0):

Update your script:

```
<h2 onclick="redirectme('<?php echo $cbox['read_more_url'];?>');" style="cursor: pointer;"><?php echo $cbox['title'];?></h2> 
<img src="<?php echo $cbox['image']['sizes']['gallery_large'] ?>" height="<?php echo $cbox['image']['sizes']['gallery_large-height'] ?>" width="<?php echo $cbox['image']['sizes']['gallery_large-width'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $cbox['title']; ?>" onclick="redirectme('<?php echo $cbox['title_url'];?>');" style="cursor: pointer;"/>
```

In javascrpt create the function like :

```
function redirectme(myurl) {
               window.location="http://" + myurl;
            }
```

Here is the example:

```
<html>
<body>

<h2 onclick="redirectme('google.com');" style="cursor: pointer;">Google</h2>


<script type="text/javascript">
function redirectme(myurl) {
               window.location="http://" + myurl;
            }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would I be able to just add that Javascript to my page at the bottom?

Comment: I have updated it but still am not able to click on them in firefox or IE. Works in chrome. This is odd.

Comment: I have added the full example...check your html with mine